# Process android.intent.category.HOME in a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to find a way to process android.intent.category.HOME in a Broadcast Receiver that sends another custom intent when the home button is pressed.

At this point I manage only to add an Activity to be used as an alternative to Google Now Launcher by adding this into the manifest:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But I don`t want to change the default Home app, I just what to let Google Now Launcher do its thing and to be also informed about the event, but it seems that if my APP is not marked as a LAUNCHER I am not able to receive the broadcast with action:MAIN and category:HOME.

Can you please help me find a solution?

Comment: Your goal is contrary to the design intent of Android.  The Home button is for taking you to the home screen - if the user has not configured that to be your app, then *it is none of your business* to know if it has been pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Intent` system in Android operates as a quasi-message bus. There are three *independent* channels on that bus:

- one channel is for starting activities, such as when the user presses the HOME button
- one channel is for starting or binding to services
- one channel is for broadcasts

The app that initiates the message is the one that chooses the channel, not you as a potential recipient. At the system level, pressing HOME triggers a `startActivity()` call to bring up the home screen. You cannot, on your own, decide that `startActivity()` should trigger a broadcast or start a service.

> it seems that if my APP is not marked as a LAUNCHER I am not able to receive the broadcast with action:MAIN and category:HOME

Even if you have an activity that is "marked as a LAUNCHER" you cannot receive the message for `MAIN`/`HOME` in a `BroadcastReceiver`, because the HOME button starts an activity.

Comment: Thanks, if the home button will only lunch an app, not sent an intent (as I was assuming), the system used for choosing what app will be used to process the HOME request ( Google Now Launcher or another app ) is different from the one used in the app chooser for selecting the app used (for example) opening a web page?

Comment: Please ignore previous post, so something like startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)) will be called when the HOME button is pressed and android.intent.category.HOME is not a broadcast intent?

Comment: @Serj: "so something like... will be called when the HOME button is pressed" -- yes. "and android.intent.category.HOME is not a broadcast intent?" -- categories are not any sort of `Intent`. Categories are strings. If I am interpreting your real question correctly, `startActivity()` does not trigger a broadcast, and that does not change based upon category.